# How to get access to DropDownList control if I add them from code

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to access a DropDownList within a div after I add them from the code-behind.
If I add DropDownList to my .aspx page like this:

```
<div id="FiltersDiv" runat="server">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListMenu" runat="server" 
                      DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id"
                    AutoPostBack="true" 
                      onselectedindexchanged="DropDownListMenu_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I can get access in any event

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var dl = addProductLocationFiltersDiv.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>();
 }
```

but not if I add from code

```
var ddl = new DropDownList();
 ddl.DataSource = flist;
 ddl.DataTextField = "name";
 ddl.DataValueField = "id";
 ddl.DataBind();
 FiltersDiv.Controls.Add(ddl);
```

I need to add several DropDownList’s and I do not now how many will be. So, I need to looping thru. 
Did I miss some attribute or how I need to do it?

Comment: Can you expand upon where you are needing to access the dropdownlists please? As by very definition, you already have access to the in code, at the point of creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a control via code, you access it through the variable name.

If you need access to several of these, consider putting then in a `List<DropDownList>` (or `List<Control>` if you have different types of controls).

If you need to *share* these across methods in your code behind, use a field instead of a local variable.

Note, that due to how the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) works, you will probably need to recreate these on every postback, otherwise you will not be able to access them. The best location to recreate such controls dynamically is in the `OnInit` handler.

Comment: I have made update to my question. I create control on Page_Load and I need to access them on some button click, can you point me some to  example or write me some, thanks.

Comment: @infoexpert.it - I did cover this in my answer. First, `Page_Load` is not the best location to create these. Try to move them to `OnInit` instead. Second - as I said, if you need to share, you should make these _fields_ instead of local variables. I also recommend reading all the information in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(DropDownList ddl in FiltersDiv.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
{
    Trace.Write(ddl.SelectedValue);
}
```

This is off the top of my head, so you may need to cast the FiltersDiv to a drop down list - As said, you'll need to make sure the controls have been recreated as soon as possible on the page before the control data is written or read.

If you try this too soon, or havn't created the controls you'll get no results.